# How do i remove these <br> tags

Tags: regex, wordpress, line-breaks

first question here :)

I'm currently experimenting with my first WordPress theme over at [http://ahrengot.com/](http://ahrengot.com), but i've come to learn that WP has the odd behaviour of throwing random line breaks into your markup.

This is a simplification of what i have:

```
<br>
<section>...</section>
<br>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<section>...</section>
<br>
```

I need to remove the line breaks before and after each section. Note that there are both br tags and ANDnbsp;'s here. I suppose i need RegEx for this, but I have absolutely no experience with that, so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very thankful :)

Comment: Wow, I really like your theme... Is it yours?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to figure out where the <br>s are originating from and eliminate them at the source? Are they appearing within posts or somewhere in your theme?

Comment: Yep – I'm thinking about releasing it for free once it's done :)

Comment: @marcy I can't control them. They WYSIWYG editor in WordPress creates them by default whenever you create your own html elements or shortcodes in the code view, unless you write everything inline which is very illegible...

Comment: Did none of these answers help? Please check the answer that was most correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of WP?

Does it add breaks when there is extra space after your elements in the HTML view? I am a Wordpress user and I don't have this problem at all. I have the "fix invalidly nested XHTML" box selected.

Here is a thread on the codex that has a suggested patch:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/empty-content-creates-an-extra-ltbrgt

Did you write the theme from scratch? If not you might want also to check your theme functions file to make sure the 'wpautop' function isn't being overridden or called with a different param.

Comment: I use the latest version. Currently 3.1.2. – Yes I wrote all the WP php stuff from scratch. The markup is based on [The HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/). Thanks for the link. I will give that a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat, but it may break other things by "hiding" the breaks. It works best if it's inside some sort of wrapping class.

```
.wrappingClass br {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I suppose I could, but that doesn't seem like the best way to go if you want clean code. Also, it doesn't take care of those ´<p>&nbsp;</p>´tags...

Answer (score 0):

You can try `<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>` at the top of your template.

Comment: looks like this might be the best way to go. I could RegEx this one, but it just feels wrong to me that WP throws in tags i didn't ask for, so manually adding them instead seems like the most sensible thing to do if I want clean code.

Comment: @Ahrengot: well, most themes are dumping out the post content inside one element, and non-developer users expect a WYSIWYG to honor their line breaks. But, yeah, its proved an annoyance to me on several occasions.